# NODE_ENV in Universal is 'none', but process.env shows 'production'

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an Angular Universal build, which uses Webpack to bundle the `server.ts` file. I know the config sets `mode: none` which sets `NODE_ENV` to none. What's confusing me is that I have `cross-env NODE_ENV=production` before the server build command, and have a console.log running, and it's displaying:

```js
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // none
console.log(process.env) // {..., NODE_ENV: production, ... }
```

I'm running the server using `heroku local`

Comment: Check type of process.env, maybe it is string.

Comment: Are these 2 console logs really together in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Anuglar Universal build, `webpack.server.config.js` sets `mode: none`, which replaces `NODE_ENV` with 'none'

The way it does this replacement is actually by replacing any references to `process.env.NODE_ENV` with the string `"none"`, as opposed to just setting the `process.env` value directly:

```
// In server.ts
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV;

// In the transpiled webpack bundled server.js
var nodeEnv = "none";
```